# Refresh model with new params

Tags: ember.js, model

I have a model that calls a query on my store. When something happens that causes the desired model to be a different query, I need to reload the data on the active route by firing the same query just with different param values.

To illustrate, when I come to my `items` route it fires a query that looks like this

```
return this.store.query('item',{auction_id: this.get('localStorage.user.user_active_auction'),user_id:this.get('localStorage.user.user_id')}).then((result)=>{
        if(result){
        return result;
        } else {
            this.get('notification').notify({message: "An error occurred trying to get items.",success:false});
            this.transitionTo('index');
        }
    });
```

The `localStorage` pieces are from a service. When the `.user` property of the service changes, I need to reload this query with the new `.user_active_auction` and `.user_id` values so new data gets placed in the template. (and thusly replaced what was there)

Can't seem to find how to do this as the `.refresh()` method reloads the cached url it used before rather than creating a new one. Not sure if maybe there is an adapter/serializer method I can implement that will allow me to tell it not to use the cached one?

Comment: The params that change, are they bound to query params?

Comment: No they are not, it's a query mostly for my back end to pick up not related to a query param setup in the controller